# Call jQuery datepicker from external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm relatively new to jQuery and am having a difficult time getting the jQuery datepicker to work from an external js file.

Originally I created the script as a function, but believed that by doing so I was limiting the scope and it would not be accessible outside the function. I've also tried defining it as a function (and naming the function), then calling it using `$(document).ready`. I cannot get it to work either way.

My external js script is called scripts.js and its contents are below:

```
$( "#from" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    altField: "#forminp1",
    altFormat: "yyddmm",
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
    }
});
$( "#to" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    altField: "#forminp2",
    altFormat: "yyddmm",
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
    },
});
```

The HTML is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Select a Date Range</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <label for="from">From</label>
    <input type="text" id="from" name="from">
    <label for="to">to</label>
    <input type="text" id="to" name="to">
    <p></p>
     <input type="text" id="forminp1" size="30">&nbsp;<input type="text" id="forminp2" size="30">
</body>
</html>
```

How can I keep the jQuery code external but have it run properly when the page loads?

Comment: use `$(document).ready(function() { //your code inside }` because your script are in the `<head></head>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the whole file in a jQuery document.ready function like [this](http://pastebin.com/BjBvarQG).

### jQuery document ready

The basics are that everything you need to run on page load needs to be inside

```
$( document ).ready(function(){ ... });
```

or the shortcut

```
$( function(){ ... });
```

See the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for more info on this.

### Script on bottom of page

You could also just put the `<script src="..."></script>` on the bottom of the page, right above the `</body>` tag.

This is generally considered to be the best practice way of doing things.

Comment: This ended up working, however I ended up having to remove another jQuery script I had in the file before it would work..there must have been a conflict. Thank you for your help.