# Create multiple external jQuery datepicker functions and call selectively

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

This is a follow up to my original post here: [Call jQuery datepicker from external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481701/call-jquery-datepicker-from-external-file)

**EDITED:**
Added correct jQuery code

I have a group of Perl reports all in one file. Most of the reports require the user to enter either a date or a date range. This would be simple if each report was in its own file, but since it's not, I need a way to call either the range-based datepicker or single date datepicker.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
        $(function () {
        $("#from").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonImage: "../images/calendar.gif",
        dateFormat: "yyddmm",
        altField: "#forminp1",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        },
        onSelect: function () {
            $(this).datepicker.val();
        }
    });

    $("#to").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonImage: "../images/calendar.gif",
        dateFormat: "yyddmm",
        altField: "#forminp2",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        },
        onSelect: function () {
            $(this).datepicker.val();
        }
    });

    $("#single").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonImage: "../images/calendar.gif",
        altField: "#forminp1",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "yymmdd",
        onSelect: function () {
            $(this).datepicker.val();
        }
    });
});
```

To test, I created an HTML file containing the following:

```
<p>Double Dates</p>
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">
<!--test the output-->
<p>Output the result</p>
<input type="text" id="forminp1" size="30">&nbsp;<input type="text" id="forminp2" size="30">
<p>Single Date</p>
<input type="text" id="single">
```

The datepicker won't attached to any of the `id`s unless I remove the function targeting the `single` id.

Is there a way to build the correct datepicker based on the `input` id?

Comment: Call what datepicker based on what exactly? Not sure I get what the condition is supposed to check here ?

Comment: Based on the `id`. In the first section, the `input id`s are "from" and "to", so I would expect the twoDates function to run. In the 2nd example, the `input id` is "single", so I would expect the oneDate function to run.

Comment: I just don't get it, if you remove the "individual functions", the datepickers are attached to the ID in the selector?

Comment: I apologize, I'm not explaining this well. In the Perl report, the `input` will always be either `$forminp1` and `$forminp2` for the to and from ranges, or `$forminp1` when only a single date is needed (this is why I used `altField`). If I just call the js file in the report, my fear is that since both the range and single input fields are defined by the same id, the javscript wouldn't know which to use . Does that make more sense?

Comment: @adeneo: I just tried removing the individual functions (along with the onSelect options) and the example won't work. I have to completely remove the function targeting the `single` id or none of the inputs display the calendar.

Comment: That sounds strange? And there's no errors in the console? Seems to work here -> http://jsfiddle.net/2crNM/

Comment: Huh. I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( `

Comment: I removed the `.val()` calls. Once I put those back in it worked a charm. Thank you SO much for your help - this was driving me crazy.